# Do I call g_free on the return from gtk_text_buffer_get_text

Tags: gtk

The gtk documentation makes it clear in most areas on whether you have to call g_free or g_object_unref on objects returned in response to a gtk function/sub call.

However, in a few locations, it is not explicitly specified or some cryptic message is specified, making the assumption that the reader is informed enough to figure it out.

In the case of gtk_text_buffer_get_text, it specifies that the returned is "an allocated UTF-8 string."

Does that mean it is an internal needed by gtk allocated string. Or is it an allocated just for my return string that has to have g_free called on it?

In general, what is the proper assumption on my part if it is not specified what to do with a string/object returned?

Answer (score 3):

The rule of thumb for returned strings is:

- `const char*` values are owned by GTK, and should not be freed
- `char*` values are allocated, and the ownership is transferred to you

In ambiguous situations, especially for random pointers, the API is annotated with a `transfer none` tag, which means the ownership is not transferred alongside the pointer, and that the *callee* still owns the data; or a `transfer full` tag, which means the owner of the pointer is the *caller*.

Comment: Thank you.  That was exactly what I was looking for.  I was probably not looking in the right places, but I could not find that information anywhere in the GTK documentation.

Comment: The annotations are documented at: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/annotation-glossary.html and https://gi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/annotations/giannotations.html